# Store URL in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute a mysql query from php.

```
$sql = insert into q_links values ( 'garment.png', 'imgs\ques\p1\garment.png' );
```

I couldn't store the url as it is, rather it is being stored like this: `imgsquesp1garment.png`. But I want to store the url like: `imgs\ques\p1\garment.png`. So I tried this:

```
$sql = mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
```

But this way my `$sql` looks like:

```
insert into q_links values ( \'garment.png\', \'imgs\\ques\\p1\\garment.png\' );
```

which do not work in the mysql database.

I have to insert this url in the database for later use. The url is `imgs\ques\p1\garment.png`. How can I achieve this?

**Update:**
And I tried with the first comment which worked for me.

**So the solution is:**

```
$sql = "insert into q_links values ( 'garment.png', '".mysql_real_escape_string( 'imgs\ques\p1\garment.png' )."' );";
```

Comment: `$sql = "insert into q_links values ( 'garment.png', '".mysql_real_escape_string( 'imgs\ques\p1\garment.png' )."' );"`

Comment: The easiest method worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the escape only for img field:

```
$sql = "insert into q_links values ( 'garment.png', '".mysql_real_escape_string( 'imgs\ques\p1\garment.png' )."' );"
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` commands anymore they are unsecure and removed in PHP 7!

Comment: Just go ahead and edit your answer to contain this fact. I recommend using `mysqli_real_escape_string` (note the `i` at the end of `mysqli`). The `i` stands for improved, also it remains in PHP7.

Answer (score 4):

```
$url = "imgs\ques\p1\garment.png";

$url = mysql_real_escape_string($url);
$sql = "INSERT INTO q_links VALUES ('garment.png', '$url')";
```

As a side note, the mysql_* functions are deprecated, and you should move to Prepared statements with [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Example in PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mydb", "user", "password");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO q_links VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array("garment.png", "imgs\ques\p1\garment.png"));
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Answer (score 2):

don't escape the single quote, only the `\`

```
$var = "insert into q_links values ( 'garment.png', 'imgs\\ques\\p1\\garment.png');"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you store it with forward slashes as such?

```
$sql = insert into q_links values ( 'garment.png', 'imgs/ques/p1/garment.png' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I can be like this:
$img=addslashes("imgs\ques\p1\garment.png");
$sql=insert into q_links values('garment.png',$img);
and while retriving you can use stripslashe();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to enter image url in database

```
$url =mysql_real_escape_string('imgs\ques\p1\garment.png');
$sql = "insert into q_links values ( 'garment.png', '".$url."' );
```

if you execute the query:
insert into q_links values ( 'garment.png', 'imgs\ques\p1\garment.png' );

it will insert successfully in database

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO. `mysql_` is deprecated anyway.

```
    $params = array('value_one','value_two')
    $dbh = new PDO('credentials go here');
    $sql = 'insert into q_links values ( ?, ? );';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
```

Using PDO you would prepare your statement and then call execute it with the exacte variable you want. It would escape it all for you.

Comment: This will fail. You haven't binded your variables

Comment: @DarylGill no need for binding. Works perfectly

Comment: @DarylGill He passes them to execute which binds them: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php